# WPF - Use DataType from parent DataTemplate inside ContentControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

So I'm defining a DataTemplate in the UserControl.Resources like so:

```xml
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Impact">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                       Text="Impact:" />
            <ComboBox Grid.Column="1"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Impacts}">
            </ComboBox>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I then have an ItemsControl define like so in the visual tree:

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ViewModelsList}">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ui:FirstViewModel}">
                    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Impact}"></ContentControl>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ui:SecondViewModel}">
                <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Impact}"></ContentControl>
                ...
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Is there a way to relate that `{Binding Impacts}` in the resources to the respective ViewModel type defined in DataTemplate's DataType?

Maybe there is a way to pass the DataType to the ContentControl?

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve here. Do you want to have two different DataTemplates for different items of the same view model type? E.g. one for the first item and another for the rest?

Comment: @Clemens The goal is to be able to assemble different ui parts depending on the viewmodel, but each part (like Impact), can be found in multiple view models.

Comment: Take a look at the ItemsControl's ItemTemplateSelector property. However "*each part (like Impact), can be found in multiple view models*" sounds odd. An ItemsControls displays a collection of item objects, which may be of different type, but always are exactly one object each. And which are each visualized by a single DataTemplate.

Comment: So basically, my ItemsControl is gonna choose which data template is displayed. Then, depending on the data template, I'll have a ui to build. The reason I put Impact as another datatemplate is that I want to be able to use Impact in my different view models. So basically you can get Impact in any of the view model objects. Then, the nested datatemplate will look for  "Impacts" in the selected View Model. Theorically, if "Impacts" is not a property of the viewmodel, then it shouldn't be called there. But if someone clumsy adds it, then it will just not find the property.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your ContentControls:

```
Content="{Binding}"
```